# How to disable Android Studio "Gradle Invocation finished" notification?

Tags: android-studio, push-notification

is there a way to disable the new "Gradle Invocation finished" Notification in Android Studio 3.5?

[image: Notification]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Alternatively, you can disable such notifications via Android Studio. Go to `Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Notifications` and uncheck `Enable system notifications` option:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Click the Notification Icon on the right side of the Windows Taskbar:

[image]

Then right click the notification and select "Turn off notifications for Android Studio":

[image]